# Do I have 2 kinds of git installed in my Mac? If so, which one will be used by default?

Tags: git

If I type on the terminal:

```
> git --version
git version 2.21.1 (Apple Git-122.3)
```

And if I type:

```
> brew upgrade git
Warning: git 2.25.0_1 already installed
```

I'm guessing, my computer has 2 kinds of git installed? If so, which one will be used by default in this case?

Also, what do you suggest I do in this case moving forward? Which one do you suggest I remove and why?

---

EDIT:

```
Also, if I type:

> git --version
git version 2.21.1 (Apple Git-122.3)

> echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/aj/.rvm/bin
```

Why is the echoed path looks weird?

Answer (score 6):

It is the usual case of keeping 2 software versions for some specific use cases if we may have.

If you will fire "git" in your terminal then the executable which will be present first in your PATH variable will get executed.

You can check your PATH by doing -

```
echo $PATH
```

You can also do

```
which git
```

to get to know from where it is getting executed. For git which comes with Mac OSX it is - "/usr/bin/git"

Homebrew generally install git at location "/usr/local/bin". If you want to use the version as installed by Homebrew; you need to append that first in your PATH.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
```

in your ~/.bash_profile followed by

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Which version is better to for general tasks (eg., github): the one from homebrew or the one from `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: It totally depends on your choice; the default Apple one should work perfectly fine.

Comment: when I typed `> echo $PATH`, I got: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/aj/.rvm/bin`. Why is this path weird?

Comment: Hi, have a look at your ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc files if you are doing an export of PATH.

Comment: My shell was zsh so I couldn't follow this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `git` installed by `brew` can be found under `/usr/local/Cellar/git/{version}/bin/git`

The git shipped by mac is under `/usr/bin/git`.

If you run `which git`, you can see which one is being used. If `/usr/bin/git`  is in use and you want the one installed by `brew`, you can run the following command:

```sh
brew link git
```

It creates a symbolic link under `/usr/local/bin` that will point to the `git` found under `Cellar`:

```sh
/usr/local/bin/git -> ../Cellar/git/2.34.1/bin/git
```

Close your terminal, and open it again.

Now if you run `which git` you can see that the `brew` one is in use:

```sh
/usr/local/bin/git
```

Answer (score 2):

I also did a brew install git.

After doing a git version I knew that I had 2 versions installed.

after an echo $PATH I noticed that path brew installs to was already there.

I closed my terminal window and opened up another one. *fix*

Now the git version command shows the correct version.

a which git command tells me I am now using the brew version.

Problem fixed.